# how do you record webcam video using asp.net mvc 3 and adobe flash media server?

Tags: asp.net, flash, adobe, webcam, record

I want to record a video from webcam in asp.net mvc 3 application and stream it to Adobe Flash Media Server to save the file for later viewing. I have googled for about 2 hours and have had no luck. I must be blind for not finding an answer. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Any links to a decent tutorial or tips?

Thanks!

Comment: You search for code to actually capture the video ? This is usually done by the software that come with the camera, or some other software that capture the video of any camera and of this web camera and stream it or save it.

Comment: What I want to do is to have users go to a webpage and there they will hit the Record button. I am planning on using the Adobe Flash to activate user's webcam. I just don't know how to stream that data to FSM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need to write an Actionscript application or a Flex application that attaches the webcam to a NetStream, and then publishes that stream to Flash Media Server (FMS). Then compile this app into SWF and embed the SWF in your asp app's HTML.

The Actionscript code for doing this with or without the Flex framework is basically the same. The concepts are:

- Get access to the webcam, Flash player automatically displays a security dialog asking the user for permission
- To display the camera output to the user, attach it to a Video object and add the Video to the stage. In a Flex application, the Video object needs to be wrapped in a Flex container (this is only difference).
- Create a NetConnection and connect it to the FMS. You attach event listeners to the NetConnection to know when it's connected (so you can proceed), or if it fails.
- After connecting, create a NetStream, attach the webcam to it, and publish to FMS.

Here's an [example](http://blog.ninethsense.com/publish-and-receive-webcam-with-flex-on-flash-media-server/) that someone else was nice enough to write.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer. I am trying out your solution. I do have another question. I would like to save this video to a file. FMS should do that for me right? If so, how can I do that?

Comment: You can trigger the recording on the client when you publish the stream, or on the FMS w/server side Actionscript using "publish" events. This [forum thread](http://forums.adobe.com/message/3148467) has some details.